# In Slider Revolution, the YouTube icon appears while the slide is changing

Tags: wordpress, slider-revolution

In Slider Revolution, the YouTube icon appears while the slide is changing. How can I make this icon not appear?

I added these codes to the custom css section, but it didn't work.

.tp-video-play-button {display: none !important}
.rev_slider video {pointer-events: none;}

Answer (score 0):

You can go to layer option -> media poster -> press youtube thumb or you can change it to any image you want to appear